# how to schedule a notification using firebase messaging

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, push-notification

I am trying to push a schedule notification to a group of people using firebase messaging, but the only resources I found were for [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications#scheduling-a-notification) with the scheduling feature. which, as far as I know, work only for the same device I work with and do not send the notification to other devices.

I tried to customize the local schedule notification to send notifications to other devices but I did not know where to add the tokens for other devices

Comment: The topic of sending scheduled messages through Firebase Cloud Messaging has been covered many times before, so without more details it is unlikely that we can help better than in these [search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+schedule+a+notification+using+firebase+messaging). Top findings: 1) you can't send direct device-to-device messages with FCM. It always requires a trusted environment. 2) there is no API to schedule sending messages in FCM. That always requires you to implement a server, or send a silent, data-only message now and schedule display on the receiving device.